# Speech to text package is not working for longer duration in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-to-text

I tried the below code from speech_to_text package from pub but i was able record only for 10 seconds or lesser and pause was also not working

```
void _startListening() async {
   
    
    await _speechToText.listen(
      onResult: _onSpeechResult,
      listenFor: Duration(minutes: 5),
      pauseFor: Duration(seconds: 5),
    
      
    );

    setState(() {
      _confidenceLevel = 0;
    });
  }

  void _stopListening() async {
    if (_wordsSpoken.isNotEmpty) {
      try {
        print(_wordsSpoken); // Update with the actual endpoint
        await uploadTrans(_wordsSpoken);
        print('Transcription sent to server.');
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error sending transcription to server: $e');
      }
    } else {
      print("no word is detected");
    }
    await _speechToText.stop();

    setState(() {});
  }
```

.